# Python - Recursively include package data in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools

Is it possible to configure setup.py so that package data are included recursively?

For example, is there an equivalent of this:

```
setup(...,
      packages=['mypkg'],
      package_data={'mypkg': ['data/*.dat']},
      )
```

which just specifies the folder (perhaps with some extra option)?

```
setup(...,
      packages=['mypkg'],
      package_data={'mypkg': ['data']},
      )
```

Examples taken from:

https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data

Comment: The only way I've been able to do it is with the [MANIFEST.in](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest-template) file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Update:

As pointed out by @AndriiZymohliad in the comments, the recursive globs are not supported by `setuptools`. You have to resolve the files programmatically. Example using `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

datadir = Path(__file__).parent / 'mypkg' / 'data'
files = [str(p.relative_to(datadir)) for p in datadir.rglob('*.dat')]

setup(
    ...,
    packages=['mypkg'],
    package_data={'mypkg': files},
)
```

#### Original answer, not working ATM

Use shell globs:

```
setup(
    ...,
    packages=['mypkg'],
    package_data={'mypkg': ['data/*.dat', 'data/**/*.dat']},
)
```

`data/*.dat` will include all `.dat` files placed directly in `data`, but not in subdirectories. `data/**/*.dat` will include all `.dat` files placed in any of the subdirectories of `data` (so it will include `data/spam/file.dat` and `data/spam/eggs/other.dat` etc), but it will **not** include any `.dat` files placed directly in `data`. Both globs are thus mutually exclusive; this is why you always need to provide both globs if you want to include any `.dat` file under `data`.

Comment: According to this https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1806 recursive glob isn't enabled on `package_data`

Comment: @AndriiZymohliad you're right. Now I'm not sure how the answer could be useful at all from the start, but I'm sure we're using globs in a project where the files collection works. Or at least worked; need to check it out next week ASAP. Thank you a lot for this valuable comment!

Comment: @AndriiZymohliad I've also changed the answer adding new snippet with programmatic collection of files instead of the recursive globs.